# Register repeated keyboard presses in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build an application where keyboard presses are captured, however I've run into the issue that if *the same keyboard presses are used successively* then shiny doesn't seem to register the input. Wondering if there is a way around this.

E.g., here's what I mean.

```
library(shiny)
runApp( list(ui = bootstrapPage(
    verbatimTextOutput("results"),
    tags$script('
    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
       Shiny.onInputChange("down", e.which);
    });'),
    tags$script('
    $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
                Shiny.onInputChange("up", e.which);
                });')
)
, server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$results = renderPrint({
        print(rnorm(1))
        c(input$down, input$up)
    })
}
))
```

Typing/releasing different characters on the keyboard generates new input, hence the random number generator is called when these events occur. But typing, say, `'g'` `'g'` `'g'` only registers the first up-down keystrokes and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Shiny.onInputChange` only reacts when the js object it references *changes*, but the way you've written your js the value is being reassigned to the same thing with multiple presses of the same key. 
An ugly workaround might be something like making the variable be the key presses and a random float in an array.

```
library(shiny)
runApp( list(ui = bootstrapPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("results"),
  tags$script('
              $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {

              Shiny.onInputChange("down", [e.which,Math.random()]);
              });'),
    tags$script('
                $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {

                Shiny.onInputChange("up",  [e.which,Math.random()]);
                });')
)
, server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$results = renderPrint({
    print(rnorm(1))
    c(input$down[1], input$up[1])
  })
}
  ))
```

It might be more efficient to eliminate the need to generate random numbers, and pass some potentially useful information back. For example using the timestamp property you could implement some filtering on the key presses.

```
library(shiny)
runApp( list(ui = bootstrapPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("results"),
  tags$script('
          $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {

          Shiny.onInputChange("down", [e.which,e.timeStamp]);
          });'),
tags$script('
            $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {

            Shiny.onInputChange("up",  [e.which,e.timeStamp]);
            });')
)
, server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$results = renderPrint({
    print(rnorm(1))
    c(input$down[1], input$up[1])
  })
}
  ))
```

Comment: That's correct.  This workaround is also what I always do. I've discussed this with Joe Cheng and it might be "fixed" at some point. [Here's the github issue for this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/928)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user5219763, though I'm not quite sure that I follow what you mean. Would you mind editing the example provided to achieve this effect?

Comment: Maybe not the best implementation but the edit should work.

Comment: Feel free to comment on that github issue to show that there are more people affected by this, it might prompt them to look into this as a higher priority :)